# List of good MFC libriares?

Tags: mfc

The reason I ask this question is there is no list available on Internet so far.

There's 
BCGSoft - www.bcgsoft.com 
CodeJock - www.codejock.com
CMarkup - www.firstobject.com
XHTML - www.hdsoft.org
UCanCode - www.ucancode.net
ProfUIS - www.prof-uis.com
Ultimate Toolkit - www.codeproject.com

Are there any good recommended MFC/ATL libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/?cat=2) hosts a large number of MFC libs, quality is variable and some older ones are now replaced by built in MFC features - but if you want it for MFC it's probably there somewhere.

And it's all free!

Answer (score 0):

Not MFC but since you also mention ATL I'd definitely include WTL in there. It stands for 
Windows Template Library and extends ATL to make it easier to make a GUI using it, more info [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/).